# Bootstrap верстка

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Я взял шаблон бутстраповский и сделал:

```css
.onesecondswidth{
    width: 50% !important;
    background-color: #112233;
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
.onesecondswidth img{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.full-width{
    width: 100%;
}.wb {
 padding-top: 35px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="full-width">
  <div class="wb"><center><h4>Примеры работ</h4></center></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://www.kulturologia.ru/files/u18214/LeonardoVecchiarino_3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LlJbpfXeNu8/Ut0AqHtC_WI/AAAAAAABL8Y/h1_cJnIEugw/s1600/Caras_Ionut_06.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://newpix.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Silvia_Cordedda_Fractals_19.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/2//69/327/69327737_1295186543_6b853289e73ft.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

И при ширине меньше 1183рх оно у меня перестает быть в ряд.

Попробовал: `display` со всеми атрибутами, в том числе и `inlie-block` и `float` зачем-то все паддинги и марджины не больше нуля.
Помогло, конечно, уменьшение ширины блока до 48% с 50%, но это не то, что нужно.

Как выставить в ряд?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете `display: inline-block`, и так как у Вас в коде присутствуют пробельные символы между блоками, то между двумя соседними inline-block'ами возникает пробел при отображении (если бы код html был минифицирован, их бы не было).

Для борьбы с этим есть 2 способа:

- кривой способ: задать отрицательный `margin`, который "уберет" пробел (плох способ тем, что размер пробела зависит от шрифта + операционной системы)
- нормальный способ: задать обертке `font-size: 0` (тогда пробел будет, но его размер известен - он 0), но есть неудобство - придется всем внутренним блокам задать font-size заново.

В данном случае (если не менять html):

```
.full-width {
   font-size: 0;
}

.full-width div {
   font-size: 12px; /* Например так */
}
```

Comment: С font-size: 0, думаю, самый оптимальный вариант :)

Answer (score 1):

Вы, вероятно, удивитесь, но достаточно убрать пробелы (и переносы строки) между блоками с изображениями - display:inline-block принимает их во внимание (правда, это не поможет в случае ie7).

```
<div class="wb"><center><h4>Примеры работ</h4></center></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://www.kulturologia.ru/files/u18214/LeonardoVecchiarino_3.jpg">
    </div><div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LlJbpfXeNu8/Ut0AqHtC_WI/AAAAAAABL8Y/h1_cJnIEugw/s1600/Caras_Ionut_06.jpg">
    </div><div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://newpix.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Silvia_Cordedda_Fractals_19.jpg">
    </div><div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/2//69/327/69327737_1295186543_6b853289e73ft.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Либо, вы можете указать float:left для класса onesecondswidth - это тоже работает.

**Edit**:
Есть и более оригинальные решения. Можно, например, избавить от пробелов между элементами с помощью пустых комментариев.

```
<div class="full-width">
    <div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://www.kulturologia.ru/files/u18214/LeonardoVecchiarino_3.jpg">
    </div><!--
    --><div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LlJbpfXeNu8/Ut0AqHtC_WI/AAAAAAABL8Y/h1_cJnIEugw/s1600/Caras_Ionut_06.jpg">
    </div><!--
    --><div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://newpix.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Silvia_Cordedda_Fractals_19.jpg">
    </div><!--
    --><div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/2//69/327/69327737_1295186543_6b853289e73ft.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Или переносить закрывающий ">" на другую строку

```
<div class="full-width">
    <div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://www.kulturologia.ru/files/u18214/LeonardoVecchiarino_3.jpg">
    </div
    ><div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LlJbpfXeNu8/Ut0AqHtC_WI/AAAAAAABL8Y/h1_cJnIEugw/s1600/Caras_Ionut_06.jpg">
    </div
    ><div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://newpix.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Silvia_Cordedda_Fractals_19.jpg">
    </div
    ><div class="col-lg-4 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/2//69/327/69327737_1295186543_6b853289e73ft.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно Вас понял, то вот так:

```css
.onesecondswidth {
      background-color: #112233;
      height: auto !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0px !important;
    }
    .onesecondswidth img {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .wb {
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 35px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="wb">
  <h4>Примеры работ</h4>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-xs-3 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://www.kulturologia.ru/files/u18214/LeonardoVecchiarino_3.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LlJbpfXeNu8/Ut0AqHtC_WI/AAAAAAABL8Y/h1_cJnIEugw/s1600/Caras_Ionut_06.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://newpix.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Silvia_Cordedda_Fractals_19.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 onesecondswidth">
    <img src="http://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/2//69/327/69327737_1295186543_6b853289e73ft.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: col-xs-(от 0 до 12) - ширина блока